# MySQL Replication Binlog file position is not being updated

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I am setting up the replication but I am facing issue that the binlog file is not being updated when I am executing any query of insert update or even creating a table. Here My Master my.cnf

```
server-id       = 1
log_bin         = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
binlog_do_db        = rep_db
```

My Master Status is as under:

```
mysql> show master status\G
 *************************** 1. row ***************************
 File: mysql-bin.000001
 Position: 107
 Binlog_Do_DB: rep_db
 Binlog_Ignore_DB: 
 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It was updating the binlog file and position in the Master status but something went wrong and its not being updated.

Comment: r u saying that entries are not updating in binary file on master server or not replicating on slave.

Comment: Yes entries are not updating the binlog file on Master server.

Comment: 1). what is your mysql version....2) there is only this db which you want to replicate or other db's also...3) how you are updating data, show some sample statements..

Comment: 1) mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.44, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
2) There is only single db which i want to replicate. 
3) I am using workbench for insert and create table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check by below 2 ways-

Method1:use sql statement as per below and check in binlog file-

```
use rep_db;
Execute your update statement here
```

Method2: Remove your db from binlog_do_db (now all db will be replicate) for testing and restart mysql service. Now check if logs are updating in binlog file.

Comment: @Baran, partial replication is a recipe for disaster.  Unless you really, seriously know what you are doing and your code is very disciplined and you have an extremely compelling reason, you will not get the expected results (as evidenced by this question).  Note that there are almost never any extremely compelling reasons.  Using `BINLOG_FORMAT=ROW` is recommended if you insist on doing it in spite of the fact that you probably shouldn't.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-rules.html explicitly states that `binlog-do-db` *should not be used*.

Comment: I completely agree with @Michael-sqlbot that if you want to play safe with replication even with stored routines then you should use row based replication and also avoid binlog-do-db as some time some dev member or some time your dba can execute any statement like db.table instead of use db; and it can currupt your slave data.